# A corrupted header and footer inserted in index.html intel xdk

Tags: intel-xdk

I have created several projects and each time a corrupted header and footer appears in the mainpage at some point. I am assuming it is a header/footer. I am unable to establish what causes this.

Has anyone experienced something similar.
My mainpage(index) comprises of 2 rows with 4 columns in the second row.
These second row has 8 image buttons that I use for navigation to 8 sub pages. The code used I then insert between the sub page div's.

This all works fine except for this weird header half blue half white header and footer. You cannot delete this header and footer from the app designer nor could I identify a line in code that could possible create this.

Comment: Which framework are you using?  Which XDK Versions are you on?  This should have been fixed in a hotfix

Comment: The version I am on is 1826. I don't know if the hotfix you mention is applied automatically or manually, in which case I'll need guidance. Another point which I don't know if this is related but maybe important. When I start a new project, select blank template, then HTML & Codava

Comment: See part of comment is missing. O use app framework. I had one or two occasions when ui framework shows unknown after creating first pages

Comment: 1826 is the hot fix version.  Any chance you can post your code somewhere so the App Designer team can investigate it?